# Автоматическое перемещение файлов из списков в указанную папку

Tags: python

Как реализовать данную идею Надо чтоб скрипт смотрел в папку (например root/server) и если в папке появлается файл из указаного списка (например test.cs) он автоматически перемещает файл в указоную директорию ( например root/server/test)

Answer (score 0):

1. Запускаете бесконечный цикл.
2. И в нем командой os.listdir(root/server) получаете список всех файлов и каталогов в данной директории.
3. Сравниваете полученный список со списком требуемых файлов. Есть много разных методов, красивый в преобразовании их к множествам a = list(set(files) & set(get_files))
4. В цикле for перемещаете файлы из списка "а" в нужную директорию командой  shutil.move(), перед этим создав пути к  файлам, типа root/server/(test) + '/' + file.
5. Командой  time.sleep(...) засыпаете на нужное время.
   Ну, и нужно импортировать в ваш файл модули из стандартной библиотеки shutil, os и time.